# index musical notes using for loop in p5.js just plays a single note. flies through the for loop despite setTimeout. will not play as expected

Tags: p5.js, synth

wish to run a for loop indexing musical notes.  runs through forloop without playing notes as expected.  have spent a few days reading docs, stack overflow, youtube coding train and still cannot get it to work as expected please help

```
let notes=["A4","B4","C4","D4"]
function setup() {

  monoSynth = new p5.MonoSynth();
  setTimeout(playStuff,1000)
}

function playStuff(){
  let i=0
  for (i=0;i<notes.length;i++){
    
    monoSynth.play(notes[i], 5, 3, 1 / 6);
    print(i)
    
  }//for i  
}//playStuff

function draw() {
  playStuff()
  noLoop()
}//draw
```

Comment: What's the "expected" way for the notes to play, and how is that different from what's happening?

Comment: thank you for your reply.  setTimeout is set to  playStuff with a 1 second delay.  It just plays one note continuously.  wish to have notes play every second

Answer (score 1):

The `setTimeout` function is only going to control when the `playStuff()` function is called, and thus when you start playing notes. Once the `playStuff()` function is called it will execute as fast as the browser can. Importantly: `p5.MonoSynth.play()` **does not block** until the not finishes playing. It simply schedules the note to be played and returns immediately. There are two ways you can achieve the desired timing: 1) Use async/away with a delay to add a time delay to your for loop; 2) Have `playStuff` take an index argument and only play a single note, but schedule itself to be called again later using `setTimeout`. I was going to suggest a third option: utilize the third parameter of `p5.MonoSynth.play()` which is the time from the present when the note should be played. However it seems that you can have only a single un-started note scheduled.

Personally I like option #1 because it doesn't substantially change the structure of the code. However it does have the downside of requiring some understanding of asynchronous programming in JavaScript.

*Note: These snippets will not produce any audio, because StackOverflow blocks audio in Stack Snippet iframes*

```js
let notes = ["A4", "B4", "C4", "D4"]

let delaySlider;
let durationSlider;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  noLoop();
  monoSynth = new p5.MonoSynth();
  let container = createDiv();
  container.style('display', 'flex');
  container.style('align-items', 'flex-start');
  container.style('height', 'fit-content');

  createSpan('Delay: ').parent(container);
  delaySlider = createSlider(1, 20, 2);
  delaySlider.parent(container);
  createSpan('Duration: ').parent(container);
  durationSlider = createSlider(1, 20, 1);
  durationSlider.parent(container);
}

let playing = false;

function mousePressed(e) {
  if (!playing && e.target !== delaySlider.elt && e.target !== durationSlider.elt) {
    playStuff();
  }
}

function asyncDelay(t) {
  return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, t));
}

async function playStuff() {
  playing = true;
  for (let note of notes) {
    monoSynth.play(note, 5, 0, durationSlider.value() / 6);
    print(note);
    await asyncDelay(delaySlider.value() / 6 * 1000);
  }

  playing = false;
} //playStuff

function draw() {} //draw
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```

### Option #2

```js
let notes = ["A4", "B4", "C4", "D4"]

let delaySlider;
let durationSlider;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  noLoop();
  monoSynth = new p5.MonoSynth();
  let container = createDiv();
  container.style('display', 'flex');
  container.style('align-items', 'flex-start');
  container.style('height', 'fit-content');

  createSpan('Delay: ').parent(container);
  delaySlider = createSlider(1, 20, 2);
  delaySlider.parent(container);
  createSpan('Duration: ').parent(container);
  durationSlider = createSlider(1, 20, 1);
  durationSlider.parent(container);
}

let playing = false;

function mousePressed(e) {
  if (!playing && e.target !== delaySlider.elt && e.target !== durationSlider.elt) {
    playStuff(0);
  }
}

function playStuff(noteIndex) {
  playing = true;
  let note = notes[noteIndex];
  monoSynth.play(note, 5, 0, durationSlider.value() / 6);
  print(note);

  if (noteIndex + 1 < notes.length) {
    setTimeout(playStuff, delaySlider.value() / 6 * 1000, noteIndex + 1);
  } else {
    setTimeout(
      () => {
        playing = false;
      },
      delaySlider.value() / 6 * 1000
    );
  }
} //playStuff

function draw() {} //draw
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time in this manner.  I am unable to upvote.

Answer (score 0):

This demo will play a note every second, one time through the array, using a timer.  If you want it to loop repeatedly, delete the noLoop() and insert counter = 0;

```
var loopTimer = 0;
let interval = 1000;
let notes = ["A4","B4","C4","D4"];
var counter = 0;

function setup() {
  monoSynth = new p5.MonoSynth();
}

function draw() {  
  if(millis() >= loopTimer){
     loopTimer += interval;
     monoSynth.play(notes[counter], 5, 3, 1/6);
    counter++;
     }
  if(counter > 3) {noLoop();}  
}
```